# Solve the system and prove that there are not other solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, systems-of-equations

> Given the system
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> \sqrt{x} = \frac{y+z}{2} \\
> \sqrt{y} = \frac{z+x}{2} \\
> \sqrt{z} = \frac{x+y}{2} \\
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Solve the system and prove that there are not other solutions.

My approach:

Let $$x=4t^2, \quad y=4k^2, \quad z=4l^2.$$
Sum all three equations and get
$$
k^2+l^2+t^2=k+l+t
$$
Then we can use full square and get

$$
\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(l-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{3}{4}.
$$

I guess that there are two solutions: $t=k=l=0$ and $t=k=l=1$, but how can I prove it?

Comment: I think your last equation has infinitely many solutions. See please my solution.

Comment: There are other $6\;complex$ solutions, like $\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3 i \sqrt{7}}{2},-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{7}}{2},-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{7}}{2}\right)$ and other $5$ with sign rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}=\frac{y+z}{2}-\frac{z+x}{2}$$ or
$$(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})(2+\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})=0,$$
which gives $x=y$.

Similarly we have $x=z$.

Thus, $x=y=z$, $x=\sqrt{x}$ and we get the answer:
$$\{(0,0,0),(1,1,1)\}$$